# Rails get routing with parameter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, routes

I want to create a new route in my routes.rb which points to a "courses" controller which has the method pdfdownload. The route is supposed to take 2 parameters: course_id and user_id. I thought it should be like this:

```
get "/courses/pdfdownload/:course_id/:user_id"
```

The courses controller and everything works fine until I add the line above. The courses controller has a method called pdfdownload. Nevertheless, when I try to start the server (rails s), I get the following error:

```
warning: already initialized constant Mime::PDF
warning: previous definition of PDF was here
Exiting
`default_controller_and_action': missing :controller (ArgumentError)
```

When I type rake:routes I get:

```
missing :controller
```

The courses controller is existing and is working very well with many methods. After I altered the line to this:

```
get "/courses/pdfdownload"
```

The server starts.

The rails guides says at "3.2 Dynamic Segments", it has to be written this way:

```
get ':controller/:action/:id/:user_id'
```

Whats wrong here? Thank you very much!

Update: I'm using the following link in the view:

```
<%= link_to "PDF", courses_pdfdownload_path(@course.id, user.id) %>
```

Comment: Maybe something like: `get "/courses/pdfdownload/:course_id/:user_id", :to => 'controller#action'` would work?

Comment: The server starts but when I open the page where the link is, I get this error: `undefined method `courses_pdfdownload_path' for #<#<Class:0x007fceafdbf990>:0x007fceafdcb1a0>`.  Thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please have a try

```
get "/courses/pdfdownload/:course_id/:user_id" => "courses#pdfdownload", :as => "courses_pdfdownload"
```

Comment: Your solution seems to be the only one that works. Could you please explain to me why the route from the guide isn't working and your does? Thanks to everyone!

Comment: You are using the route helper "courses_pdfdownload_path" in your view. You can see this route helper is not showing in the output while you have not defined it explicitly. So, I have added :as => "courses_pdfdownload" and I got your route helper in the rake routes.

Comment: Thank you very much! Does this mean that if this route helper (on the left site at rake:routes) is missing, there is actually no route I can call for this method?

Answer (score 1):

try `match "/courses/pdfdownload/:course_id/:user_id" => "courses#pdfdownload"`

Answer (score 1):

The correct route would be:

```
get '/courses/pdfdownload/:course_id/:user_id', to: 'courses#pdfdownload'
```

But for a nicer REST route, I would rather change it to this:

```
get '/courses/pdfdownload/:id/:user_id', to: 'courses#pdfdownload'
```

The fact that the action deals with a `Course` resource is already implied by the name of the controller handling the action. So you don't need to call the `Course` id `:course_id`, simply `:id` is enough.

**Edit**

Note also that you can customize the name of the route helper like this:

```
get '/courses/pdfdownload/:id/:user_id', to: 'courses#pdfdownload', as: 'courses_pdfdownload'
```

Your route helper will then be `courses_pdfdownload_path`.

Answer (score 1):

As for the errors,

```
warning: already initialized constant Mime::PDF
warning: previous definition of PDF was here
```

this is due to Rails registering PDF by default since 2011.  No need to register them in config anymore.

https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/d73269ba53992d8a01e5721aad3d23bc2b11dc4f